# is it possible to limit memory usage for a while loop?

Tags: python

I have a simple script that has a single function responsible for outputting a list of floats, I want to be able to call that function from the script in a `while True` loop to get the list of floats every time the function gets called, it saves/caches the list to the RAM which keeps growing until it has no space left and then crashes

is there any way to call the function and output the list then remove it from the ram or limit the python script to use a defined size of RAM portion e.g 2GB

I tried using `runpy` but I was not successful and I don't want to go that way

In other words how do you pop the manipulated `lst` from the RAM so that the next list will take it place

what do you do when you want your script to run for long periods of time

script_A with function

```
def create_lst(x):
    ### make a list with that a has a length of 10000  float numbers and return it
    ### x is a integer that goes into the calculation of the float numbers  
    return lst
```

the main_script

```
import time 
from script_A import  * 



def manipulate_lst(lst):
    # do some calculations on the lst and print out some results 


while True:
    lst = create_lst(x)
    manipulate_lst(lst)
```

Comment: Well why do you cache them in RAM when that's not what you want?

Comment: With the example code you have given, the `lst` variable is reused every new iteration, and should thus not increase the memory size: the memory used by the previous `lst` variable, now defunct, should be cleared by the garbage collector.

Comment: You could try and run the garbage collection explicitly each iteration of the loop after `manipulate_lst`: `import gc` (garbage collection module), then in the loop `gc.collect()`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html . But from my experience, this rarely helps a problem like yours, and it is possible that the actual underlying problem is elsewhere, and that the memory is still retained (in code not shown here).

Comment: Have you tried commenting-out the `manipulate_lst` call, and see if the problem still occurs? And if not, try a simpler form of `manipulate_lst`, commenting-out parts in that function. That way, you might be able to find the culprit by elimination of code.

Comment: @HeapOverflow as far as i know when you run a script it get loaded into the RAM with all the data it generates, am i wrong?

Comment: I tried using garbage collector it helps but does not eliminate the problem

Comment: If you reassign the variable to a new object and there are no other references to it (as your code pretends to be the case), then Python will reuse the memory. Why would it keep things around that can't get used anymore? The Python implementors aren't stupid.

Comment: @HeapOverflow That is probably the question the OP is asking, just in a different way.